# Require at least one word boundary

Tags: regex

I am looking to create a regex that allows either one or two word boundaries, but not zero.

For example, for the word `term`:

- `a term is` <-- yes, space before and space after (two boundaries)
- `the terms are` <-- yes, space before (one boundary)
- `the midterm was` <-- yes, space after (one boundary)
- `the midterms were` <-- no (zero word boundaries)

Would would be the best regex for this? My initial thinking was:

- [`\bterm|term\b|\bterm\b`](https://regex101.com/r/pFTnxG/4) # (no `?` on `\b`)

But this seems way too verbose. What might be a better one?

Comment: @No -- I can retype it to make it more clear.

Comment: @CarySwoveland updated.

Comment: I think you just want `\bterm|term\b`

Comment: @Dai yes that's correct, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Dai Works perfectly fine in regex101. See for yourself: [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/RpZG62/1)

Comment: @samuel Please kindly upvote my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a conditional:

```
(\b)?term(?(1)|\b)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/nl1TpN/1). If there is a word boundary in front, do not enforce it at the end. Else, require a word boundary at the end.

If a conditional is not available, use alternation:

```
\bterm|term\b
```

See [another proof](https://regex101.com/r/nl1TpN/2).